# How to redirect url/index.php to url/home

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having an issue with magento in multiple languages ​​at home only.

If it works this way:

```
url/pt/index.php or url/pt/home
```

If remove `index.php` or `home` is directed to the default language

The server is not directed, because I think it does not generate the url already directs straightforward.

So I want to try the htaccess is:

```
url/pt redirect to url/pt/home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule **as your very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /pt(/index\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /pt/home [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/index\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /home [L,R=301]
```